# What is the event that occur on the browser when Firebug is enabled?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firebug

I am working with SPRFlat Boostrap template. I am facing a problem, when I maximize the browser window after I minimize it. That is some CanvasJS graphs overlap. I need to refresh the page to fix the issue. However, when I enable the Firebug to debug the issue, I noticed that all the panels get reset.

I try to work with jQuery reset but it create another issue. My question is when the Firebug is enable what is the event occur on the browser? If I know it then I can handle the issue.

But if anybody can give me a hint to fix my main issue, that's also appreciated.

Comment: Firebug doesn't really trigger events, but the window gets smaller, it's probably the `window.onresize` event that is doing it !

Comment: If Firebug doesn't fire any events we can just do some research to see what changes, if any prefs change we can set a watcher on that pref. If UI elements change we can set a mutation observer on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug does not expose any event to the website content.

To avoid Firebug influencing the viewport dimensions you can detach it using the [image: Firebug Detach button] button at the upper right side of the Firebug window.